# Php with excel sheet updating for particular column

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel sheet.I need to update particular column value(getting from database)...
How I can update multiple table when i importing excel sheet....

Answer (score 0):

you can use csv to get the data using csvreader class. you can google csvreader class. and you can get rows and columns and you can loop through them by row and by column. from there you can insert your database records.